# How do I dynamicly add <select> tags based on another <select> value?

Tags: javascript, forms, select, dynamic

For a registration form I'm looking for a way to give the user more  options based on a number (#) they choose in an  formfield.

I've searched and found a way to do this with javascript but it does not allow the  tag, it does however accept  etc. but not a dropdown menu field.

```
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Step 2/3: Virtual Machine Options</legend>
                    <div>
                        <label for="vmammount">Order # VM's</label>
                        <select name="vmammount" required="required">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">3</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>                        
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="vmos">VM OS 1</label>
                        <select name="vmos" required="required">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">Windows Server 2008</option>
                            <option value="2">Windows XP</option>
                            <option value="3">Debian</option>
                            <option value="4">CentOS</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
<div>
                        <label for="vmos">VM OS 2</label>
                        <select name="vmos" required="required">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">Windows Server 2008</option>
                            <option value="2">Windows XP</option>
                            <option value="3">Debian</option>
                            <option value="4">CentOS</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
```

The OS 1 field is always visible, the other selection field that will follow are dependent on the first  field in which the user chooses a value from 1 till 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your phrasing is a bit unclear. Are you looking to create a <select> with <option> tags? Then of course creating <input>'s won't work.

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes that's correct. So I want the user to choose a value that I staticly program with <option> tags. Basec on the value the user chooses more <select> (dropdownboxes) will apear or disapear all based on the value that the user chooses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create all os selection elements in HTML / PHP ... but only display them if nessesary. Here an example with jQuery, its also possible with plain javascript but needs at least 10times mutch lines of code.

http://jsfiddle.net/vuPwM/2/

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Step 2/3: Virtual Machine Options</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="vmammount">Order # VM's</label>
            <select name="vmammount" id="vmammount" required="required">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">3</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="vmos_block">
            <div class="vmos" id="vmos_block_1">
                <label for="vmos_1">VM OS 1</label>
                <select name="vmos[1]" id="vmos_1" required="required">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">Windows Server 2008</option>
                    <option value="2">Windows XP</option>
                    <option value="3">Debian</option>
                    <option value="4">CentOS</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="vmos" id="vmos_block_2">
                <label for="vmos_2">VM OS 2</label>
                <select name="vmos[2]" id="vmos_2" required="required">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">Windows Server 2008</option>
                    <option value="2">Windows XP</option>
                    <option value="3">Debian</option>
                    <option value="4">CentOS</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="vmos" id="vmos_block_3">
                <label for="vmos_3">VM OS 3</label>
                <select name="vmos[3]" id="vmos_3" required="required">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">Windows Server 2008</option>
                    <option value="2">Windows XP</option>
                    <option value="3">Debian</option>
                    <option value="4">CentOS</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="vmos" id="vmos_block_4">
                <label for="vmos_4">VM OS 4</label>
                <select name="vmos[4]" id="vmos_4" required="required">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="1">Windows Server 2008</option>
                    <option value="2">Windows XP</option>
                    <option value="3">Debian</option>
                    <option value="4">CentOS</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
</fieldset>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.vmos').hide();

    $("#vmammount").change(function () {
        $('.vmos').hide();

        if ($(this).val() < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = 1; i <= $(this).val() ; i++) {
              $('#vmos_block_' + i).show();          
        }

        return true;
    });
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: I think I asked the question wrong and/or posted the code wrong, sorry. :( I've edited my original post. Thanks for your thought so far guys! It's still not working atm

Comment: @user1949628 i changed my answer to match to your new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, http://supunk.blogspot.se/2009/01/creating-select-list-using-javascript.html

This is some slightly modified code

```
var numSelects = 3; //change this to the value of the first select
var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
for(var i = 0; i <= numSelects; i++)
{
/* create select */
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.setAttribute("name", "mySelect_" + i);
select.setAttribute("id", "mySelect_" + i);
select.style.width = "300px";

var option;

for( var j = 0; j <= 5; j++ )
{
 /* we are going to add two options */
 /* create options elements */
 option = document.createElement("option");
 option.setAttribute("value", "value_" + i "_" + j);
 option.innerHTML = "Text #" + j + " in box #" + i "!";
 select.appendChild(option);
 }
 foo.appendChild( select );
}
```

Comment: I think I asked the question wrong and/or posted the code wrong, sorry. :( I've edited my original post. Thanks for your thought so far guys! It's still not working atm

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create N amount of `select`s based on the input of the first `select`? I've updated the code in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding your question, but you can do this pretty easily with a framework like [Knockout.js](http://www.knockoutjs.com) which allows you to define a client-side view model to handle the state of your registration form.

View Model

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.vmaValue = ko.observable(1);
    this.vmaOptions = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Markup

```
<select data-bind="options: vmaOptions, value: vmaValue"></select>

<!-- ko if: vmaValue() === 1 -->
<div>
    <label for="vmos">VM OS 1</label>
    <select name="vmos" required="required">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Windows Server 2008</option>
        <option value="2">Windows XP</option>
        <option value="3">Debian</option>
        <option value="4">CentOS</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: vmaValue() === 2 -->
<div>
    <label for="vmos">VM OS 2</label>
    <select name="vmos" required="required">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Windows Server 2008</option>
        <option value="2">Windows XP</option>
        <option value="3">Debian</option>
        <option value="4">CentOS</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->​
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vEQ9d/ Note that this example is greatly simplified and you can do a lot more with Knockout then what I'm showing here including dynamically building the OS drop downs with a JSON response from the server, it's just hard to show all of that in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using jQuery:

```
$("#labelID").change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()){
        case "1":
            $("#VMOS1").show();
            break;
        case "2":
            $("#VMOS2").show();
            break;
    }
})
```

This is just a rough example you should add ids and classes to your elements.